# How to read Prolog documentation?

Tags: prolog, interpretation

If, for instance, I type `help(bagof).` into the Prolog REPL, a window pops up with some documentation, the first line of which reads `bagof(+Template, :Goal, -Bag)`.

1. Are the arguments Template, Goal and Bag just names, or are they formal types that can be systematically researched? (In the first case I would have to rely on the documentation of `bagof` to make sense of them; in the latter case I would be able to refer to some other document.)
2. Where can I find documentation for those bits of punctuation preceding the arguments? (In this case the punctuation includes the symbols `+`, `:` and `-`, but I've seen others.)

Comment: Related: [This](/a/8294290/772868), [that](/a/19386816/772868), and [that](/a/23312956/772868).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Template`, `Goal` etc. are simply *names* of these arguments. Sometimes, they give some indication about the expected *type* of the respective argument. For example, `Goal` typically indicates an argument of type `callable`. A name like `List` typically indicates a list, and so on.

`+`, `:` etc. are *mode indicators* and denote the expected instantiation patterns:

Quoting from http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modes:

```
++  Argument is ground at call-time, i.e., the argument does not contain a variable anywhere.
+   Argument is fully instantiated at call-time, to a term that satisfies the type. etc.
-   Argument is an output argument. etc.
--  Argument is unbound at call-time. etc.
?   Argument is bound to a partial term of the indicated type at call-time. etc.
:   Argument is a meta-argument. Implies +.
etc.
```

The most commonly used mode indicators are `+`, `-` and `?`.

Note also that there are different conventions and slight variations for documenting such properties of predicates that are also used in the literature and in the documentation of some systems.